# Repeating Background with SpriteKit and Swift

Tags: ios, swift

Im playing around with swift and i would like to make a simple game using SpriteKit. In the background of the app is texture image that should repeat.

I mean like [img][img][img][img]

How can i do this?

In aditional I want to move it forever. But I already solved this part.

Here is my code:

```
 func generateWave(){

    var wave: SKSpriteNode = SKSpriteNode(imageNamed: "wave")

    var moveWave = SKAction.moveByX(-wave.size.width * 2.0, y: 0, duration: NSTimeInterval(0.02 * wave.size.width * 2.0))
    var resetWave = SKAction.moveByX(wave.size.width * 2.0, y: 0, duration: 0.0)
    var moveWaveForever = SKAction.repeatActionForever(SKAction.sequence([moveWave,resetWave]))

    wave.position = CGPoint(x:CGFloat(1),y:CGFloat(10))

    wave.runAction(moveWaveForever)

    self.addChild(wave)

}
```

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow. You are better off creating multiple rectangular sprite nodes placed side by side.

Comment: Or I can make the image just bigger. Which of these methods is the most efficient?

Comment: Negligible differences in efficiency. Though multiple rectangular sprites are more scalable for smaller/bigger screens.

Comment: Please make sure you post your solution as an answer to this question when you are done with it, to help future visitors.

Comment: Users with less than 10 reputation can't answer their own question for 8 hours after asking. -> Quite stupid rule, isn't it?

Comment: Oh only if you knew the reasons for having that rule in the first place. Too many spam bots.

Comment: okay :( Sad. Does swift has any func to set a color using RGB which gives me photoshop?

Comment: Suggest you google around for that. Comments on a post should remain on topic.

Answer (score 2):

Try using a for loop after making your background move. Like this:

## #

```
    bgTexture = SKTexture(imageNamed: "wave")
    var movebg = SKAction.moveByX(-bgTexture.size().width, y: 0, duration: 9)
    var replacebg = SKAction.moveByX(bgTexture.size().width, y: 0, duration: 0)
    moveForever = SKAction.repeatActionForever(SKAction.sequence([movebg, replacebg]))
    for var i:CGFloat=0; i<3; i++ {

        wave = SKSpriteNode(texture: bgTexture)
        wave.position = CGPoint(x: bgTexture.size().width/2 + bgTexture.size().width * i, y: CGRectGetMidY(self.frame))
        wave.size.height = self.frame.height

        wave.runAction(moveForever)

        self.addChild(wave)
```

}
 ##

I hope this helps!